# How I can I Substring XAttribute Value from LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have some ugly xml(if I could change I would) coming to me that I need to be able to process. I wanted to group by a specific attribute in the XML for further processing.  The problem is that some of the attributes have a type="A" and some have type="A1", type="A2", etc.  I want all of the elements that have an attribute type value that starts with "A" be grouped together.

This is not working and I don't know what to change to get it to work:

```
    var result = from ele in xdoc.Descendants(Namespace + "item")
                 let item= ele.Attribute("type").Value.Substring(1,1)
                 group ele by item into grp
                 select grp;
```

When I take off the substring it works fine, but obviously doesn't group how I want.

Error:

```
Error has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

Example XML:

```
<items>
 <item type="A" position="0">
   <itemvalue>10</itemvalue>
 </item>
  <item type="A1" position="1">
    <itemvalue>20</itemvalue>
 </item>
  <item type="A2" position="2">
    <itemvalue>30</itemvalue>
 </item>
  <item type="B" position="0">
    <itemvalue>10</itemvalue>
  </item>
   <item type="B1" position="1">
     <itemvalue>20</itemvalue>
  </item>
   <item type="B2" position="2">
     <itemvalue>30</itemvalue>
 </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a compiler at my disposal and typing this on my mobile I would say that you should pass 0 as the first argument to `Substring`, i.e. `Substring(0,1)`.

Comment: Oh my gosh thanks for making look like a complete idiot...that was totally it thanks @afrischke.  I am a sql dev and didn't even think about the 0 position in the substring.

Comment: Don't worry, I have made (and certainly will make) far more embarrassing mistakes myself.